# Find using $lt and $gt with javascript Dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to fetch results from a MongoDB collection. Here's an example of it:

```
{ "entryDate" : "2012-10-14T00:00:00.000Z", "amount" : 1, "cardId" : "50786621e3b983f1078d0bc9", "_id" : ObjectId("507a17354c6cbd6a4b000001"), "addedDate" : "Sat Oct 13 2012 21:36:53 GMT-0400 (EDT)" }
{ "entryDate" : "2012-10-10T00:00:00.000Z", "amount" : 21, "cardId" : "50786639e3b983f1078d205e", "_id" : ObjectId("507a17394c6cbd6a4b000002"), "addedDate" : "Sat Oct 13 2012 21:36:57 GMT-0400 (EDT)" }
{ "entryDate" : "2012-10-09T00:00:00.000Z", "amount" : 1, "cardId" : "50786639e3b983f1078d205e", "_id" : ObjectId("507a25e46af510804c000002"), "addedDate" : "Sat Oct 13 2012 22:39:32 GMT-0400 (EDT)" }
{ "entryDate" : "2012-10-08T00:00:00.000Z", "amount" : 12, "cardId" : "50786621e3b983f1078d0bc9", "_id" : ObjectId("507a2603b7a095824c000003"), "addedDate" : "Sat Oct 13 2012 22:40:03 GMT-0400 (EDT)" }
{ "entryDate" : "2012-10-08T00:00:00.000Z", "amount" : 1, "cardId" : "507865e1e3b983f1078ceb3f", "_id" : ObjectId("507a2667b7a095824c000004"), "addedDate" : "Sat Oct 13 2012 22:41:43 GMT-0400 (EDT)" }
{ "entryDate" : "2012-10-15T00:00:00.000Z", "amount" : 2, "cardId" : "50786621e3b983f1078d0bc9", "_id" : ObjectId("507a48c170b1a26f4f000001"), "addedDate" : "Sun Oct 14 2012 01:08:17 GMT-0400 (EDT)" }
```

Here's the query I'm trying to execute: (this is collection)

```
// (these are JS Date objects)
// start =  Sun Oct 7 2012 13:22:02 GMT-0400 (EDT)
// end =  Sat Oct 20 2012 13:22:02 GMT-0400 (EDT)

this.find({ cardId: cardId, entryDate: { $lt : start, $gt : end } }).toArray(function(err, entries) { console.log(err, entries) });
```

But unfortunately, it always return `[]` and no errors.

Any ideas? I'm surely doing something wrong, but I've been searching for so long that I'm askign for your help.

Thanks a lot nad have a nice day!

Comment: It should be $lt and $gt, instead of &lt and &gt.

Comment: Oh lol, made a typo while transcribing. Not working with $. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
this.find({ cardId: cardId, entryDate: { $lt : start, $gt : end } }).toArray(function(err, entries) { console.log(err, entries) });
```

Here is how I tested it. Insert scripts looked like this one:

```
db.samples.insert({ "entryDate" : new Date(2012, 10, 9), "amount" : 1, "cardId" : "50786639e3b983f1078d205e" })
```

Lookup query is this one:

```
db.samples.find({ entryDate: { $gt : new Date(2012, 10, 7), $lt : new Date(2012, 10, 20) } }).count();
```

Comment: As I said in the post, I tried and it doesn't work. Always return [] and no errors.

Comment: The query seems to be correct - it worked on my instance with your example, should be a problem with the data or filter parameters.

Comment: I'm sure it's with the data, I tried all the example I found. I'll double check something with my dates in the collection. Thanks for the help.

Comment: How did you store your dates in your example?

Comment: Updated my answer with the test scripts

Answer (score 1):

Your date range is backwards.  It should be:

```
this.find({ cardId: cardId, entryDate: { $gt : start, $lt : end } })
    .toArray(function(err, entries) { 
        console.log(err, entries) 
    }
);
```

Comment: This obviously was one part of the problem. I tried it in the console and it works, now just make it work in the code hehe. There must be something wrong with the date I use in start and end maybe... Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: It works with only one constraint but when I add another one it doesn't. `{ entryDate: { $lt: Date('2012-10-30') }}` works but not `{ entryDate: { $gt: Date('2012-10-01'), $lt: Date('2012-10-30') }}` Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TomShreds You need to use `new Date(...)`, not just `Date(...)`.

Comment: Tried it and it does the same. Thanks

Comment: @TomShreds Those strings you're using aren't parseable by the `Date` constructor.  The string must conform to RFC2822 or ISO8601; [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).  For example: `'Oct 1, 2012'`

Comment: @TomShreds Is `entryDate` a string in your docs or a Date?  If it's a string like it looks in your question this won't work and you would need to convert it to a Date.